# worklight Server with multiple database installations

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Does anyone know if it is possible to install more than one database in Worklight Server?
Reason for that; I have different underdevelopment applications, developed using different databases (DB2,MySQL, and Derby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some flaws in this question...

1. you do not install databases in Worklight. Rather, Worklight uses the database you choose to use for it.
2. You do not develop applications using databases. Rather, your applications communicate with databases and other backend systems (in the case of Worklight, using adapters).

**The answer is No.**
In worklight.properties you may specify only 1 database type for Worklight Server to work with.

In Worklight 5, 1 Worklight project = 1 Worklight Server instance, with its own specific setup.

A Worklight project may contain several applications, depending on how and what you develop. This way you could switch them all to use the same database type.

**Extra:**

The only time where you can specify another, different or not, database type is when you have Reports enabled. This, however, would not be a recommended approach. You shouldn't use different database types for the same instance of Worklight.

Also, the concept you mention is not possible in Worklight. For different applications to communicate with different databases, it means your applications belong to different Worklight projects, which means that each project belong to a different Worklight Server. In this case, if you have multiple Worklight Servers, then sure, each server can work with a different database, but you cannot have 1 Worklight Server to communicate with multiple databases, each catering for a different Worklight project.